# How to stop the DebugView tool through command line parameters

Tags: debugview

In my project I want to start the DebugView tool through command line parameters to capture kernel logs automatically, but after finishing a task I want to stop this DebugView tool. How do I stop this tool through command line parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want,

1. You could:

   ```
   taskkill /IM dbgview.exe
   ```

   But that might not guarantee all logs a written to the output file (I'm not sure what would happen).
2. You could use Debugview++ UI from https://github.com/djeedjay/DebugViewPP/releases

   And define a 'stop' filter. This would stop the scrolling, but not stop collection of the data.
3. Leave a comment at https://github.com/djeedjay/DebugViewPP/issues/270 which I just filed to add a commandline option to do just this ;) And I will implement it.

Comment: Hi Jan,      Thanks a lot for you clarification.                                                                                                          It would be good if you provide support "stop" in debugview to stop capturing the debugview logs and close this tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help.